# Most frequently tools or programming language for implementation text processing and nlp algorithms in academic papers and journals

Tags: programming-languages, data-mining, natural-language-processing

I want to prototype and try some idea (some algorithm) in the field of text processing and nlp and if the results was good I want to publish some paper or journal article about that.

I am familiar with Weka, RapidMiner, Matlab and Python for text processing and nlp but I don't know what is the most frequently tools for those fields in the academic area?

As you know, comparing results with others is one of the most important parts of any academic paper. For this reason, I want to choose most frequently tools or language for this work.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The tools used should make no difference for the results, other than the running time, which is usually not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but running time is important for me because some part of my work is about optimization. 
Which tools you have seen more to implement in the articles?

Comment: You're welcome to look at some relevant articles yourself and prepare the statistics you're after.

Comment: Thanks @yuval-filmus. I've asked this question to check if someone has already done such a statistics. Because re-invention of the wheel is not logical.

Comment: The exact tools used could potentially depend on the sub-area, which is why I suggested you take a look on relevant papers in your sub-area.

Comment: You should definitely say more precisely what kind of algorithms you wish to develop and experiment if you wish your question to be reopened. You can do that by editing your question. My own answer could be written because it is about your methodology rather than more specific issues, such as adequacy of specific tools.

Answer (score 2):

My personnal opinion is that such comparisons usually make little
sense because they can be too dependent on hidden specificity of tools
or programming languages, or programming style and its interaction
with those specificities.

In my opinion, the only proper way to compare techniques is by a precise knowledge of
the interpretation machines. If you are comparing different algorithms
intended to achieve the same purpose, you want to run them on some
kind of unbiased abstract machine, providing some application
meaningful primitives than can be used to implement on the same
footing all the algorithmic variations.

Then you can actually count elementary computation costs over some
chosen benchmark.

For example, I have seen this type of work done for various parsing
algorithms, using a standardized PDA definition.

Making a slightly better tool than what exist for problem X in
language Y is seldom worth publishing, unless there is some more
abstract consideration of some theoretical work that shows that you
are bringing something to the field, rather than just being a better
hacker. And then the tool or language support does not matter so much,
as long as you can compare with some known work, and explain credibly
why your version works better.

Of course, if you actually manage to get major improvements, undisputable ones, then you have a much better chance of being published. But the the technical support you use will matter even less.